# HTML5 Video Poster Not Displaying Safari

Tags: html, video, safari

My video poster appears in Chrome / Firefox but is not displaying in Safari.  My play button appears and I can play the video, but the poster is a no show.  Mark up is below.  Any thoughts?

```
         <video id="video" controls poster="/assets/img/background/simon.jpg">
           <source src="/assets/img/video/want-it.webm"
                   type='video/webm;codecs="vp8, vorbis"'/>
           <source src="/assets/img/video/want-it.mp4"
                   type='video/mp4;codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'/>
          <object data="" type="" class="simon">
            <img src='/assets/img/background/simon.jpg' title="Your browser does not support video">
          </object>
         </video>
```

Comment: UPDATE - I just added preload="none" to the video element and the poster loads, but only after I refresh the page.  Any ideas?

Comment: have you watched in network tools (timeline, Network request) to see if the poster is being requested

Comment: I've seen the same issue on some machines. After refresh everything is fine. It starts out as blank image space. Works fine in all other browsers, it only is Safari that seems to have some issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thats coz its the default safari behaviour they load the video as soon as its first frame is ready to play. one thing that temporarily shows the poster is to set the `preload` attribute to none on the video tag. `preload="none"` but again the poster will go away as soon as the video disappears. Following is a hacky way I did it in React but you can adjust it for any framework:

First I detect whether the browser is safari or not using the following in a useEffect:

```
var isSafari = /^((?!chrome|android).)*safari/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
```

then I set it inside a state object.

If safari is true then instead of displaying the video i simply display an image with that poster as its source. Then I have an onClick handler on the image tag itself clicking on it will change the above state back to false and hence image component will stop showing and video will be shown instead. Now one more problem you would have to tackle here is that on image click the image will disappear and video will appear and you'll then have to click the video again for it to play. That's bad UX. so for that you can simply attach a ref to the video and inside the click handler for Image after you set the state simple do :

```
videoRef.current.play()
```

This will start playing the video as well.
I know this is a hacky solution so don't come at me but it was the only thing i could do to get it work.

Answer (score 0):

I solved that issue by adding ***#t=0.001*** at the end of the file's URL inside  `<video>` tag.

```
<video>
  <source src="path-to-video.mp4#t=0.001" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Check [this](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/129377) for more info.